# Convert string to datetime using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column which contains string as datetime and I am trying to convert the
column to date. Even though the snippet does not throw out an error it returns zero(00:00:00), I request your kind guidance on how to convert the Week column into MM/dd/yyyy date format.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas import DataFrame

third = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/emailcombo.csv')
third = third.rename(columns={'Phone Number:': 'Phone Number:'})

fourth = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/The_Real_InfoCenter.csv')
fourth = fourth.rename(columns={'Phone Number: ': 'Phone Number:'})

merged = pd.concat([third, fourth], ignore_index = True)

df = DataFrame(merged)
df['Week:'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Week:'])
df.sort_values(['Week:'], ascending = [False])

df.to_csv('Z:/AWS/updatedinfocentertracker.csv', index=False)

print "Updating has been done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you provide a section of your data. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df['Week:'] = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(d) for d in df['Week:']])
df.sort_values(['Week:'], ascending = [False])
```